# HMC5883L tilt compensation

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I have a HMC5883L 3-axis magnetometer. I would like to add tilt compensation to my Arduino Uno project.

Since the IC has 3 axis that it measures (X,Y,Z) is it possible to add tilt compensation without an accelerometer? If yes would this how do I find an equation to do the calculation. Is this equation found from http://bluelemonlabs.blogspot.fi/2013/08/arduino-simple-compass-with-hmc5883l.html correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need an accelerometer.

If you read the article you link to you can see this bit:

> There are many margin of improvement. First, we ought compensate the potential tilt of the device using the accelerometer data from the ADXL345, for example using the info on [my previous post](http://bluelemonlabs.blogspot.it/2013/08/arduino-imu-pitch-roll-from-adxl345.html)!

To do tilt compensation you need three axes of both magnetometer data and accelerometer data to scale and merge those three axes.